# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]input:checkbox[name=]:checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a form with jquery 1.11.1, but the checkboxes do not work! which is the syntax error?

```
$(this + "input[name=''] :checked").each(function() {
totalSum += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: you can't use `this` plus a string as a selector. and remove that space before `:checked`

Comment: `[object HTMLDivElement]` is the syntax error in the selector. `this` is a **DOM element**. What did you expect from concatenating a **DOM element** with a **string**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use something like this:

```
$( this ).find( "input[name='']:checked" ).each(function() {
  totalSum += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Using `find()` you can search for elements, which are descendants of a given element.

---

Anyway, are you sure you want to search for `<input>` elements, which have a `name` attribute set to an empty string? Because that is, what you are currently selecting.

Comment: Don't forget about `$("input[name='']:checked",this)`, which is the same as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different...

```
var totalSum = $(this)
.find("input[name='']:checked")
.map(function() { return parseInt(this.value, 10); })
.get()
.reduce(function(total, value) { return total + value; }, 0);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `get()`? Which prototype does that come from?

Comment: @Sirko Turns it into a real array. It's on jQuery's, as I'm calling it directly on a collection.